# Ramsey Measurement for Characterising a Qubit

Tags: decoherence

I'm trying to understand the Ramsey measurement used to characterise dephasing effects in qubits.

When operating on resonance, I understand the following quantum gate diagram to describe the $T_2^*$ dephasing time.
[image]

I specify on resonance so that the the evolution operator implementing $X_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ exactly implements the rotation matrix around the x axis through an angle of $\pi/2$ (up to a global phase).

During the $t_{\text{wait}}$ time the qubit experiences free evolution. During the free evolution the qubit may experience dephasing, where the off-diagonal terms of its density matrix tend towards zero. I model this with the Lindblad equation and the decay transition $L_{\downarrow} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ from $|1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$:
$$\begin{align}
        \frac{d\rho}{dt} &= -\frac{i}{\hbar}[{H},\rho] + \gamma\left(L_{\downarrow}\rho L_{\downarrow}^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{L_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}L_\downarrow, \rho\}\right)\\
                         &= \begin{pmatrix}
                             \gamma\rho_{11} & \left(-\gamma/2 + i\frac{\mu_{B}}{\hbar}\right)\rho_{01}\\
                             \left(-\gamma/2 - i\frac{\mu_{B}}{\hbar}\right)\rho_{10} & -\gamma\rho_{11}
                         \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align}$$
The rate of the decay transition is $\gamma$ and I was looking at a spin coupling to a magnetic field so that's why the Bohr magneton $\mu_B$ appears. For completeness the Hamiltonian $H$ is:
$$
    \begin{equation}
        {H}  = -\mu_B\begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0\\ 0 & -0.5 \end{pmatrix} 
    \end{equation}
$$

I then carry out the Ramsey experiment.

1. First apply $X_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$
2. Evolve qubit density matrix using Lindblad and decay transition
3. Apply $X_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$
4. Measure in computational basis

With this I find the following plot:
[image]

The exponential decay envelope is as I expect, with a $T_{2}^{*} = 2/\gamma$ for the decay process. We can see this in the final form of the Lindblad equation I showed earlier.

One short question here, are these oscillations called Ramsey fringes? I can't find a clear definition for what exactly the term Ramsey fringe refers to.

My main question is then, how do I reproduce a plot like the following, where we now carry out the same Ramsey experiment but off-resonance. The following is taken from:

- “A fault-tolerant addressable spin qubit in a natural silicon quantum dot.” Available: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.1600694

[image]

I would like to reproduce Figure B above. My understanding here is that the frequency on the x-axis is that used to carry out the rotations around the x-axis. However, given that we are off-resonance, I would assume we wouldn't achieve exactly $\pi/2$ rotations anymore. The 2 state evolution operator I'm using is based off Section 12.4 in "J. A. Bergou, M. Hillery, and M. Saffman, Quantum Information Processing: Theory and Implementation. in Graduate Texts in Physics. Cham: Springer International Publishing, 2021. doi: 10.1007/978-3-030-75436-5.":

\begin{align}
    U &= \begin{pmatrix}u_{11} & u_{12}\\u_{21}&u_{22}\end{pmatrix}\nonumber \\
      &= \begin{pmatrix}
     e^{i\left(\frac{\omega - \omega_0}{2}\right)t}\left(\cos(\omega_r t) - i\frac{(\omega - \omega_{0})}{2\omega_r}\sin(\omega_r t)\right) & -\frac{i\Omega_{ab}}{\omega_r}e^{i\left(\frac{\omega - \omega_0}{2}\right)t}\sin(\omega_r t)\\
     -\frac{i\Omega_{ba}}{\omega_r}e^{-i\left(\frac{\omega - \omega_0}{2}\right)t}\sin(\omega_r t) & e^{-i\left(\frac{\omega - \omega_0}{2}\right)t}\left(\cos(\omega_r t) + i\frac{(\omega - \omega_{0})}{2\omega_r}\sin(\omega_r t)\right)
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

The driving frequency is $\omega$, the resonant frequency $\omega_0$, rabi frequency $\omega_r$, and off-diagonal $\Omega_{ab} = V_{ab}/\hbar$, with the driven Hamiltonian $\begin{pmatrix}E_{a} & V_{ab}e^{i\omega t}\\ V_{ba}e^{-i\omega t}& E_{b}\end{pmatrix}$

So my approach to recreate this plot is then:

1. Apply rotation gate but using off-resonance evolution operator. I currently use the same time of evolution as I did for on-resonance. There is no decoherence in this step.
2. Evolve the state using the Lindblad equation as before with a decay transition for a range of times.
3. Apply same rotation gate off-resonance for the same amount of time. Again, no decoherence.

Is this correct? I was expecting to reproduce Figure B but find quite different results. First off , figures similar to Figure B are shown in many qubit characterisation papers but don't show any oscillation in the probability over time. I would have expected there to be oscillations in the probability over time as I showed for the on-resonance case. Here's an example of a plot for a small bandwidth around resonance I produced, though it really doesn't look promising:

[image]

There is quite possibly an issue with the code I've written to create this, sampling the frequency and time correctly is something I definitely need to check. I can provide the code if needed but what I'm mostly wondering is if my overall approach with regards to the physics looks correct.